# Which wood dimension to run on top of fence?

Tags: wood, outdoor, fence

For the below picture, is it a 2x4 or 1x2 on top? Also how does it attach to the pickets? Is it nailed/screwed to the posts?

I can't really tell.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a 2x4.   It would look better on both sides of the fence if it were a 2x6 or 1x6, because then it would fully cover the posts.  Nail them down from the top, into the 4x4 post.

Comment: I am thinking about running something on top but using 1x4 on the side instead. The reason is that my fence already have 2x4 running on the other side of the fence (about 6 inches below the top line). That 2x4 was already there. I just need to put something on top to make the top line straight / even. Is it OK to do so? Meaning would 1x4 too weak and pop out? I plan to attach this 1x4 to the posts on both sides.

Comment: I can't visualize what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to use a 1x4 as a trim piece.   It will be fine and will not pop out, if properly nailed, whether it's to the side as a trim piece or on the top as a cap.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I wanted to do 1x4 trim because the top wasn't even due to the slope where I have the fence.